# Customer was allowed to checkout with invalid zipcode

Tags: shipping

A customer put in an invalid zipcode.  They put in SS059  instead of 33059. Like the letter S.  Somehow it still allowed them to complete the checkout process. I tried to duplicate this by going through checkout myself and using invalid zip codes but it stopped me from checking out with a error message saying no shipping method was available for me.

However it has allowed this customer to do it.

The other issue is that it failed to charge her any shipping. The shipping doesn't even show up on the order. It's blank.

Any ideas or thoughts on what I should check first? This is the third order that has made it through the cart that failed to charge any shipping, but this is the first one that had an invalid zipcode.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have Free Shipping enable in System->Configuration->Sales->Shipping methods or in Shopping Cart Price Rules. That's why the shipping doesn't show up on the order.

Please check your Shipping methods configuration for Default, Website, Store